# Measure tool: different results with/without snap

Tags: snapping, measurement

as you can see in the picture, I'm getting different results when measuring with/without snap.
The last 3 measures do not use snap, while the rest do (either one side snap or two sides snap)
The objects are a small cube (1mm x 1mm) on top of a big cube.

It also happens that when measuring, without holding control, from the left edge of the big cube to the left edge of the small cube, I get 1 mm, but when I hit/hold the control key, it automatically changes to around 1.8 mm. The 0.996638 mm uses no snap.

The 2.3768 mm I get when starting without snap and then the end point with snap. The 2.52483 uses snap on both ends.
The 1.83096 uses no snap
The 1.83705 mm uses snap in both ends.

[image: Blender measure tool with/without snap]

How can I prevent this? or why is this happening?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your screenshot looks a bit messy and hard to understand and your explanation is also confusing with a bunch of random measurements. Can you share your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your screenshot is not very clear and your explanations what you are snapping to aren't very clear either. The only thing I can see is you are seemingly measuring in *Top Orthographic* view, but I have no idea how your geometry looks like.

So, I did the same with my own geometry and in the following screenshot the upper length `3.00162 m` is measured with snapping, the lower value `2.14531 m` is measured without snapping:

[image: measured with snapping]

Now these values are quite different - how can this be? Well, looking at the measurements in *Front Orthographic* view makes it quite obvious: the measurement with snapping was measured snapped from a lower edge to a higher edge, while the measurement without snapping was simply measuring straight horizontally at the height of the 3D cursor. Of course the diagonal length is more than the horizontal length:

[image: measured without snapping]

This is just hypothetical since you don't provide enough information on the geometry you are measuring, but it is a possible explanation of what is happening there.

Comment: exactly the scenario that's most likely happening!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Not the first time that someone is confused about results from the _Measure_ tool. I'm sometimes just wondering why people make the effort to get screenshots and write a question with lengthy explanations but don't bother to take a look from a different perspective at what they are actually measuring. But at least it gives us the opportunity to help with answers :)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. It's all about 3D... 
I'm very new to Blender and have no prior experience with other software, so I see that the "orthographic" view is... a "view" and doesn't actually "flatten" the objects. I even used the "user" view, but flat, and the measures where the same... but when I rotated the view a bit, I could see that the snap tool was actually starting from the bottom edge.
I also just found out that when there's an "x" inside the circle, it seems to pick the bottom one, while when the circle is "empty" it picks the top one... thanks again!

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yeah i actually have answered the same thing on another question with similar scenario here haha https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271709/measuring-and-setting-exact-distance-between-two-objects